# Git roto : git add . da error: short read No such file or directory

Tags: git

No sé porque pero en un momento cuando traté de agregar mi progreso a mi depósito que tenía :

```
(MoodEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/Moodbot$ git add .
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Entonces intento de nuevo pero me dice que un fichero ya existe :

```
(MoodEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/Moodbot$ git add .
fatal: Unable to create '/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/Moodbot/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

Por eso :

```
(MoodEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/Moodbot$ rm .git/index.lock 

    error: short read No such file or directory
    error: MoodEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libfuturize/fixes/__pycache__/fix_UserDict.cpython-35.pyc: failed to insert into database
    error: unable to index file MoodEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libfuturize/fixes/__pycache__/fix_UserDict.cpython-35.pyc
    fatal: updating files failed
```

#### Actualización 31/05/2018

No estoy seguro de que eso sea lo que funcionó, pero hizo :

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```

Y ahora me dice :

```
(MoodEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/Moodbot$ git add .
(MoodEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/Moodbot$ git commit -m "milestone : ready to work, don't forget to add the true credentials"
[master 5db6840] milestone : ready to work, don't forget to add the true credentials
 19 files changed, 2127 insertions(+), 524 deletions(-)
 rewrite models/dialogue/policy_1_KerasPolicy/featurizer.json (92%)
 rewrite models/dialogue/policy_1_KerasPolicy/keras_arch.json (100%)
 rewrite models/dialogue/policy_1_KerasPolicy/keras_weights.h5 (73%)
(MoodEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/Moodbot$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': antoinecomp
Password for 'https://antoinecomp@github.com': 
Counting objects: 23662, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (20906/20906), done.
Writing objects: 100% (23662/23662), 392.91 MiB | 1.41 MiB/s, done.
Total 23662 (delta 3553), reused 11501 (delta 2261)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3553/3553), completed with 13 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 18f9ed182009e2704aa994c425387a10
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File MoodEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/en_core_web_md/en_core_web_md-2.0.0/vocab/lexemes.bin is 123.03 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File MoodEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so is 112.42 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot4.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot4.git'
```

Parece que la razón porque no funciona esta a causa de un fichero que pesa mas que 100Mb. Es extraño porque pensaba que los añadí todos en el `.gitignore` pero tal vez uno se añadí. Aquí esta el `.gitignore` :

```
/MoodbotEnv/*
```

Intentando eliminar los archivos de gran tamano que que alguna vez pasaron por control de versiones siguiendo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164610/parece-que-git-ya-tuvo-en-cuenta-los-archivos-agregados-en-gitignore) obtuve :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/Moodbot$ git rev-list --objects --all |\ 
 git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectsize) %(rest)' |\ 
 awk '$1 >= 100 * 2^20' |\ 
 sort --numeric-sort --key=1 |\ 
 numfmt --field=1 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest
 112MiB MoodEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
 123MiB MoodEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/en_core_web_md/en_core_web_md-2.0.0/vocab/lexemes.bin
```

Pero para eliminar ese archivo de la historia para siempre, no funciona como en la respuesta, parece haber algún compromiso para hacer :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/Moodbot$ git filter-branch -f --index-filter 
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch 
MoodEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' HEAD
Cannot rewrite branches: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás intentando pushear archivos que pesan más de 100Mb y github no permite eso. Yendo más allá, no tienes por qué tener bajo control de versiones las dependencias del proyecto.

Sería más sensato quitar esos archivos del control de versiones añadiendo `MoodEnv` al `.gitignore` y eliminarlos con  `git rm --cached -f MoodEnv`.

Sin embargo ya tienes esos archivos versionados, de manera que aunque los quites, siguen en tu historial y al hacer push intentará subir la referencia a esos archivos por el sólo hecho de que alguna vez estuvieron versionados.

La solución sería hacer

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch MoodEnv' HEAD
```

Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164610/parece-que-git-ya-tuvo-en-cuenta-los-archivos-agregados-en-gitignore/164874#164874) para el procedimiento completo.

Al quitar el contenido de tu virtualenv del control de versiones, el resto de los colaboradores tendrán que recrear el virtualenv cuando quieran trabajar en el proyecto. Para eso tendrás que tener versionado el archivo `requirements.txt` con las dependencias.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
git add requirements.txt
git commit requirements.txt -m "añade requirements.txt"
```

Y luego tus colaboradores, si no tienen el directorio de virtualenv, tendrían que crearlo e instalar las dependencias (por ejemplo con  `venv`):

```
python3 -m venv "MoodEnv"
source MoodEnv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Y repetir el `pip install` cada vez que se añada una dependencia al proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya tengo une archivo `requirements.txt` ¿El comando `pip freeze > requirements.txt` lo sobrescribirá? ¿Es serio?

Comment: Porque [el mío](http://textuploader.com/dpkrc) parece bastante diferente de [ella](http://textuploader.com/dpkr6). O al menos, menos organizado.

Comment: Si no quieres sobreescribir el requirements puedes omitir ese paso, pero la gracia de usarlo es que se sacará una foto de lo que tengas instalado en el virtualenv. De paso puedes ver si sigue instalado un paquete que ya no vas a usar.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución si tienes el proyecto subido a un repositorio es hacer un clone del proyecto , coger el fichero `.git` y a partir de hay haces el commit.

1. Borras el `.git` que tienes o mejor , lo copias cambiándole el nombre por si encuentras una solución más óptima.
2. Clonas el repositorio de nuevo en otra carpeta con distinto nombre.
3. Copias el `git` de ese repositorio , al que no le funciona correctamente el comando `git` , donde puedes hacer ya los comandos míticos.

   git add .

   git commit -m ""