# ¿Por qué no me ignora el archivo .project gitignore?

Tags: gitignore, gitkraken-git-gui

Estoy empezando a utilizar GitKraken, en el archivo `.gitignore` le estoy diciendo los archivos que quiero que me ignore, pero en gitkraken me sale el archivo `.project` en naranja para comitear, añado `.project` en el `.gitignore` y no me lo oculta. Solo me pasa con los archivos que en gitkraken tienen el simbolo naranja para comitear.

¿Como puedo ocultarlo?

Comment: ¿Una vez añadido al `.gitignore`, has hecho `commit` del mismo?

Comment: No, a no ser que antes lo hayan comiteado, que es lo más probable. Únicamente me pasa con los archivos que salen con el simbolo naranja.

Comment: Para que `git` ignore los ficheros añadidos a `.gitignore`, es necesario hacer `commit` del `.gitignore` modificado.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Parece que Git ya tuvo en cuenta los archivos agregados en .gitignore](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164610/parece-que-git-ya-tuvo-en-cuenta-los-archivos-agregados-en-gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

A mi me pasaba, despues de añadir un fichero, no se quita del repositorio aunque lo pongas en el .gitignore, tienes que quitarlo maunualmente del repositorio.

```
$ git rm --cached ruta_del_fichero
```